# PHP Hello world.I am newbie

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Why my browser don't show "Hello world",but trying to save the file(helloworld.php)?
Sorry for stupid question.

Comment: you saved this file as helloworld.php on the server and went to it in a browser?  So like www.domain.com/helloworld.php

Answer (score 2):

PHP pages only run on a PHP webserver. You can't just give a textfile a .php extension and double-click it. Make sure

1. You have a webserver (e.g. Apache HTTPD) installed.
2. You have PHP installed.
3. Make sure the PHP file is in your webroot (e.g. htdocs)
4. You go to the page via a URL that hits the server (e.g.
   `http://localhost/page.php`)

Comment: Well, that's not true.  PHP has a CLI as well...

Comment: Lol. Oliver, sure you can run console PHP code from a command line, but this question is obviously not trying to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to open your php file directly with the browser on your local computer.

1) You can run it from localhost (on your own computer). Try installing XAMPP http://www.apachefriends.org/. BTW, portable XAMPP (without installation) is also available.

2) You can run it from hosting provider that supports php. Just register at some free one and upload your file to the www directory.

Answer (score 0):

on linux-systems with apache this is a known bug. reinstalling the libapache2-mod-php5filter fixes this.
for linux-systems with apt packet-manager the command would be`

```
apt-get reinstall libapache2-mod-php5filter
```

Answer (score 0):

install Wampserver [download wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper)

step one install it ....

step two after successfull instalation you will see a "W" icon in your task bar [image: wamp icon in task bar]

step three right click on icon put online

step four place your php files in "c:/wamp/www"  folder

```
   type localhost in browser u will find u r file there click on it enjoy :)
```